# Responding a 204 status code

Tags: iis, asp-classic

How can I answer a "204 No Content" http response with classic ASP ?

When I simply send an empty response with the following code :

```
Response.Clear
Response.End
```

I style get an answer on the client-side. IE9 open a window with an empty (but valide) html file.

I just need to know how to properly return a 204 from an ASP page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[204 isn't an error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).  It's an indication of a successful request, but simply without a response.  (Think of it like the HTTP equivalent of the `void` return type for a method.)

Are you sending a 204 to your client?  From the code shown I would guess what you're actually sending is a 200 response with no content, which is not the same thing.  If that's the case, the web browser is behaving correctly by displaying the (lack of) content being returned.

**Edit**:  Re-reading your question, are you asking how to properly return a 204 from an ASP page?  It wasn't clear at first.  If that's the case, take a look at the [Response](http://psacake.com/web/gz.asp) object.  Specifically, for the `Status` property:

> A string which specifies the value of status line of the server. It is included in HTTP headers of the response. This string should contain both three digit code and a brief explanation for it e.g. "404 File Not Found".

In this case, try:

```
Response.Status = "204 No Content"
```

Comment: I edited my question, I need to know how to properly return a 204. I should have called it a "status code", not an error code.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow, at the office.

Comment: Does not work... The client (IE9) recieves that : "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> <HTML><HEAD> <META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD> <BODY></BODY></HTML>"

Comment: I used wireshark, the serveur code works. It is IE9 which add code.